# How to prevent data clear while implementing pagination with recyclerview + GSON

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gson

I need to prevent data clear while implementing pagination. I used the below code to deserialize the JSON response and feed in my adapter.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<MyDataModel> mcontentList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(getResponse, MyDataModel.class));
        mAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mcontentList.get(0).getResponse().getCoreContent());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Everything working fine for the first set of data, while i added scroll more/pagination the next set of data replaced my old data, advise me to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are every time clearing out old data.

In your adapter add this method

```
void addData(List<MyDataModel> newData){
  for(MyDataModel data:newData)
  listData.add(data);
}
```

and then

```
if(mAdapter==null){
    mAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mcontentList.get(0).getResponse().getCoreContent());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
else{
mAdapter.addData(mcontentList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyDataAdapter` create one method public and set adaptor with empty list before calling this method

```
void addData(List<Your Object> mcontentList){
               yourList.addAll(mcontentList);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
                                           }
```